# Problems with Pom.xml

Tags: eclipse, maven, pom.xml

I hope you guys can help me out.
I want to make a simple webLogin (Maven project) so far my code works. Now to make a build and deploy it i had to look into poms and i really tried but i don't know what i am doing wrong.  Maybe someone knows how to do it right

My project tree:

[image: The tree of my Project]

pom.xml(project)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>LoginTest</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>LoginTest</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

pom.xml(app)

```
<project 
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>src.main.java</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>LoginTest</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>



    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <env>dev</env>
                <exclude-ui>false</exclude-ui>
                <api.ctx.root>/rest</api.ctx.root>
                <ui.ctx.root>/webui</ui.ctx.root>

            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>


</project>
```

pom.xml(rest)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>src.main.java</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>LoginTest</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>src.main.java.app</groupId>
            <artifactId>Login.java</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
                    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/*intf*.jar,WEB-INF/lib/*shared*.jar</packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

pom.xml(webui)

```
<project 
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>src.main.java</groupId>
    <artifactId>webui</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>LoginTest</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>



    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <env>dev</env>
                <exclude-ui>false</exclude-ui>
                <api.ctx.root>/rest</api.ctx.root>
                <ui.ctx.root>/webui</ui.ctx.root>

            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>


</project>
```

This is what i get right now and im sure this will not be the last ERROR i get..

```
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for src.main.java:app:1.0.0: Could not find artifact org.apache.maven:LoginTest:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 12, column 10 -> [Help 2]
```

Maybe someone can help me thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your project structure seems to be broken. You usually have *one* pom per project, and especially you should not have pom files in the src/main/java. If you want to define modules (subprojects) they need to have their own inner structure (as every Maven project).

Comment: I removed the pom files now except for the one in the root project folder. Building without Errors now thank you :)

Comment: Good. If my answer was useful, please upvote and accept it. Thank you!